# Simplify for precision

Tags: machine-precision

I have an a set of equations to solve — details irrelevant — the result of which will be [converted into PostScript](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101954/), a 1980s printer-control language the only floating precision of which is single. Therefore I care about precision.

Consider a simple case, in which there are floating-point variables (or parameters) *x* and *y*, and small integer parameters *i* and *j* (small in the sense that any relevant combination of *i* and *j* is below integer overflow). Consider the following:

```
(* Seven floating-point operations, four multiplies, three additions *)
ansA = 2 x i + 3 x j + 5 y i + 7 y j;

(* Seven floating-point operations, four multiplies, three additions *)
ansB = (2 x + 5 y) i + (3 x + 7 y) j;

(* Three floating-point operations, two multiplies, one addition *)
ansC = (2 i + 3 j) x + (5 i + 7 j) y;

And[ansA == ansB, ansA == ansC, ansB == ansC] // Simplify
```

Clearly, precision arguments favour the last of these. Please, how can Mathematica’s `Simplify` (or `FullSimplify`) best be commanded to find the precision-optimal expression? If relevant, I have four integers parameters, and three floating-point parameters.

Comment: I think the details are actually relevant here. The expression you give can be written as a matrix-vector contraction `{i, j} . {{2, 5}, {3, 7}} . {x, y}`. As usual in such expressions, the order of contraction matters. Contracting from the left allows staying in the integers longer (your `ansC`); contracting from the right means switching to floats right away (your `ansB`). So if your expression in general can be written in this form (or similar), then arguing through contraction-order will help.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think MA can do this kind of optimization for such small expressions. But you can play with `Compile` in order to see how it is evaluated:

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}}, 
             Evaluate@ansA, 
             "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed", 
             CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}]
```

You can printed generated code:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[cf]

    4 arguments
    6 Integer registers
    7 Real registers
    Underflow checking off
    Overflow checking off
    Integer overflow checking off
    RuntimeAttributes -> {}

    R0 = A1
    R1 = A2
    I0 = A3
    I1 = A4
    I4 = 5
    I2 = 2
    I5 = 7
    I3 = 3
    Result = R2

1   R2 = I2
2   R3 = I0
3   R2 = R2 * R3 * R0
4   R3 = I3
5   R4 = I1
6   R3 = R3 * R4 * R0
7   R4 = I4
8   R5 = I0
9   R4 = R4 * R5 * R1
10  R5 = I5
11  R6 = I1
12  R5 = R5 * R6 * R1
13  R2 = R2 + R3 + R4 + R5
14  Return
```

Notice that in more complicated [cases](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182061/9469) this approach works.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that counts the involved operations (addition, multiplication) and remembers which ones of them involve floats and which ones involve only integers. This is of course a simplistic model of precision or complexity; but maybe it can be of use for you.

```
SetAttributes[{myplus, mytimes}, Orderless];
operations[A_] := Module[{B, R},
  (* substitute integers by "i" and floats by "f" *)
  B = A /. {Plus -> myplus, Times -> mytimes} /.
           {i | j -> "i", x | y -> "f", _Integer -> "i", _?NumericQ -> "f"};
  (* execute the formula and remember operations *)
  R = Reap[B //. {myplus[a : ("i"|"f")..] :>
                    (Sow[p[a]];If[Union[{a}]==={"i"},"i","f"]),
                  mytimes[a : ("i"|"f")..] :>
                    (Sow[t[a]];If[Union[{a}]==={"i"},"i","f"])}][[2, 1]]];
```

Notice how in the definition of `R` the floating-point numbers are "contagious" in that a sum or product involving at least one float results in a float.

As an example, we define the complexity of a formula as the number of multiplications involving at least one floating-point number:

```
complexity[A_] := Count[operations[A], t["f", __]]
```

Let's try it out: the three given formulas contain different numbers of floating-point multiplications:

```
ansA = 2 x i + 3 x j + 5 y i + 7 y j;
ansB = (2 x + 5 y) i + (3 x + 7 y) j;
ansC = (2 i + 3 j) x + (5 i + 7 j) y;

complexity[ansA]
(*    4    *)

complexity[ansB]
(*    6    *)

complexity[ansC]
(*    2    *)
```

We can use this complexity function in [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) to discover `ansC` automatically:

```
FullSimplify[ansA, ComplexityFunction -> complexity]
(*    (2 i + 3 j) x + (5 i + 7 j) y    *)
```

Different choices for `complexity` will give different results here, and some experimentation may be needed.

### Update: more detailed complexity function

A more detailed complexity function would count the total number of [binary operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation) that involve at least one floating-point number. For example, $x+y$ would be one such operation; $x+i$ would be one; $x+i+2=x+(i+2)$ would be one (because $i+2$ can be done in the integers); $x+y+2$ would be two floating-point operations.

```
complexity[A_] := 
  Total[operations[A] /. (t | p)[a : ("i" | "f") ..] :>
          Count[{a}, "f"] - Boole[FreeQ[{a}, "i"]]]
```

Try out this complexity function:

```
complexity[ansA]
(*    7    *)

complexity[ansB]
(*    9    *)

complexity[ansC]
(*    3    *)

FullSimplify[ansA, ComplexityFunction -> complexity]
(*    (2 i + 3 j) x + (5 i + 7 j) y    *)
```

Comment: This could be excellent. I will test and try to make it recognise addition and subtraction. Maybe adding a LeafCount÷1000000.

Comment: @jdaw1 Please note that subtraction is represented as addition internally: for example, `FullForm[a - b]` shows an internal representation of `Plus[a, Times[-1, b]]`, which is $a + (-1)\cdot b$. So there is no need to treat subtraction differently from what I've presented.

Comment: Please, why `Orderless`? Consider 7+i+x, which is one floating operation, but x+i+7 is two. They aren’t the same.

Comment: [`Orderless`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) because of [commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). As for multi-argument operations like $7+i+x$, what I've proposed is a bare-minimum simplistic implementation that you are free to extend in the directions you suggest, if that's what gets you closer to a solid heuristic for precision.

Comment: @yarchik I think I need to convert to a form like yours, but strictly binary (which I’ll name, PostScript-style, `add` and `mul`), and then tell Mathematica that the binary `add` and `mul` are each commutative and associative, and jointly distributive (please, clues about how to this would be welcomed). That would allow Mathematica to hold differently `7 i add f add` (better) and `7 i f add add` (worse) (written in PostScript’s reverse Polish notation). Then your complexity function can guide M’s optimisation in the wanted direction. This is a plan.

Comment: Thank you. Great progress, in [20210720_complexity.nb](http://www.jdawiseman.com/2021/20210720_complexity.nb). I’m stuck on one thing. How can `FullSimplify` be told that `add` and `mul` are commutative and associative, and jointly distributive, without making them flat? Not flat because if non-binarily flat then Mathematica will re-order alphabetically, and the float/int ordering will be messed about.

Comment: The likes of the following don’t seem to help `FullSimplify`.
Assumptions -> {
   mul[a_, b_] == mul[b, a],
   add[a_, b_] == add[b, a],
   mul[mul[a_, b_], c_] == mul[a, mul[b, c]],
   mul[a_, mul[b_, c_]] == mul[mul[a, b], c],
   add[add[a_, b_], c_] == add[a, add[b, c]],
   add[a_, add[b_, c_]] == add[add[a, b], c],
   mul[a_, add[b_, c_]] == add[mul[a, b], mul[a, c]],
   add[mul[a_, b_], mul[a_, c_]] == mul[a, add[b, c]]
  }  

@Roman